# Why does the text in this JFrame not blink?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I was working on an example in *Learning Java: 4th Edition* from O'Reilly when I came across this program:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class HelloJava4 {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("HelloJava4");
    frame.add(new HelloComponent4("Hello, Java!"));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
}

class HelloComponent4 extends JComponent implements MouseMotionListener, ActionListener, Runnable {
String theMessage;
int messageX = 125, messageY = 95;

JButton theButton;

int colorIndex; //Current index into someColors
static Color[] someColors = {Color.black, Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue, Color.magenta};

boolean blinkState;

public HelloComponent4(String message){
    theMessage = message;
    theButton = new JButton("Change Color");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    add(theButton);
    theButton.addActionListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
}

public void paintComponenet(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(blinkState ? getBackground() : currentColor());
    g.drawString(theMessage, messageX, messageY);
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    messageX = e.getX();
    messageY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() == theButton)
        changeColor();
}

synchronized private void changeColor(){
    if(++colorIndex == someColors.length)
        colorIndex = 0;
    setForeground(currentColor());
    repaint();
}

synchronized private Color currentColor(){
    return someColors[colorIndex];
}

@Override
public void run(){
    try{
        while(true){
            blinkState = !blinkState; //Toggle blinkState
            repaint(); //show the change
            Thread.sleep(300);
        }
    } catch(InterruptedException ie){}
}
}
```

The program is supposed to make the text "Hello, Java!" in the blink in the box. For some reason, the text doesn't even appear. The JButton that says "Change Color" is there but it doesn't work (or I am unable to see it work because there is no text in the JFrame/HelloComponent4).

I am not familiar with Swing or AWT so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're not truly overriding the paintComponent method since
`paintComponenet != paintComponent`

Always pre-pend all methods that you *think* you're overriding with the `@Override` annotation since this way the compiler will *warn* you at compile time when your assumptions are incorrect.

Also side issue: call the `super.paintComponent(g)` method in your own override so that the component does its own housekeeping painting, including ridding empty pixels.

e.g., change this:

```
public void paintComponenet(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(blinkState ? getBackground() : currentColor());
    g.drawString(theMessage, messageX, messageY);
}
```

to this:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(blinkState ? getBackground() : currentColor());
    g.drawString(theMessage, messageX, messageY);
}
```

Myself, I'd use a Swing Timer and a JLabel to do this rather than threading and painting.

Or at least a Swing Timer. For example:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class HelloJava4b extends JPanel {
    // don't have component class implement listener interfaces
    private static final int PREF_W = 400;
    private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
    public static final Color[] COLORS = { Color.black, Color.red, Color.green, Color.blue,
            Color.magenta };
    private static final int TIMER_DELAY = 300;
    private static final Font TEXT_FONT = new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 40);
    private int colorsIndex = 0;
    private boolean blinkState = false;
    private String text;
    private int messageX = 125;
    private int messageY = 95;

    public HelloJava4b(String text) {
        this.text = text;
        add(new JButton(new ButtonAction("Change Color")));

        // create Swing Timer and start
        new Timer(TIMER_DELAY, new TimerListener()).start();

        // create mouse listener and add
        MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();
        addMouseListener(myMouse);
        addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
    }

    // size component per its preferred size
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
            return super.getPreferredSize();
        }
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Color c = blinkState ? getBackground() : COLORS[colorsIndex];
        g.setColor(c);

        // make rendering smoother
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(TEXT_FONT);  // and bigger
        g.drawString(text, messageX, messageY);
    }

    // button's Action
    private class ButtonAction extends AbstractAction {
        public ButtonAction(String name) {
            super(name);
            int mnemonic = (int) name.charAt(0);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-char hot key
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            colorsIndex++;
            colorsIndex %= COLORS.length;
        }
    }

    private class TimerListener implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            blinkState = !blinkState;
            repaint();
        }
    }

    // my combination mouse listener and motion listener
    private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
        private boolean moving = false;

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
                return;
            }
            moving = true;
            messageX = e.getX();
            messageY = e.getY();
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // if not moving, then right button not pressed
            if (moving) {
                messageX = e.getX();
                messageY = e.getY();
                repaint();
                moving = false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            if (moving) {
                messageX = e.getX();
                messageY = e.getY();
                repaint();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        HelloJava4b mainPanel = new HelloJava4b("Hello All!");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello Java");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  This was very helpful

Comment: @NiteshKartha: you're welcome. Note edits to answer.